# Is it possible to plant tardigrade DNA into a human? What would happen even if?

Tags: dna, stem-cells, human

So I have been reading a WEBTOON (A distant sky) and the 2 mcs have tardigrade stem cells in them which gives them the abilities tardigrades have. I am aware that the story is obviously fictional, but I was wondering if it is possible? What would happen?

Comment: Welcome Pluto. Could you read the [ask] section of the [help] and [edit] to include more (much much more) specific details of what you're referring to in terms of the specific "genes", where and in what cells you'd transplant the "genes" and in what position on which chromosomes, and your own research into the topic. You could do worse than start with this paper: [Extremotolerant tardigrade genome and improved radiotolerance of human cultured cells by tardigrade-unique protein](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5034306/)

Comment: This is like asking what would happen if you put helicopter parts into a bicycle.

Comment: Well thank you Jim for answering properly unlike some

Comment: These are comments not answers. You're still expected to edit the question to show your own research as per the [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, parts of tardigrade DNA that code for specific proteins or abilities could potentially be isolated and inserted into human cells in vitro. Getting them into a living human is technically possible, but nothing like that has been done. This doesn't mean the process would result in any tardigrade-like effects in the human cells.

However, tardigrade survival is a complex system, not a single superpower gene. You can't just insert 'the tardigrade gene'. Multiple systems would need to be altered successfully for anything close to tardigrade-like resilience. Even if a tardigrade protein was successfully integrated into a human cell, we don't know what would happen because that protein will interact with the rest of our human biology.

As the comments indicate, this is entirely dependent on the specific gene you insert. There are many genes, and each can have a different effect. Many genes also need other systems or other genes to function properly. Also, inserting tardigrade stem cells into the body is different from inserting *genes* into human cells.